# Apart from USR1 and USR2, which signals can I safely use for custom interrupting behavior? (in python)

Tags: process, python, kill, signals, interrupt

I have a complex application with USR1 and USR2 already defined as having a well-defined and not replaceable purpose.

There are tons of different signals in linux. Might there be another one (maybe a deprecated one) that can be safely used without expecting the OS to trigger destructive behavior?

Comment: It really depends on your application, and on what you want to do.  For example if your application is a daemon and you want to tell it to print its status to a file, you could use `SIGHUP`.

Comment: SIGHUP is also commonly used to reload a daemon's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In that case:

> you could use SIGHUP

At least using Kubuntu those available signals can also be used: SIGRTMIN SIGRTMAX SIGRTMIN+1 SIGRTMIN+2 and similar ones that can be seen using `kill -l`.